# rvest 1.0.0 - Latest Update Incompatibility

Tags: r, json, web-scraping, rvest, httr

**The goal:** Log in to a website using rvest.

**The problem:** My code no longer works with rvest (Version 1.0.0).

**What worked:** Code using the previous version of rvest (Version 0.3.6):

```
rg.headers <- c('User-Agent' = 'Mozilla/5.0')
rg.url <- "https://rotogrinders.com/"
rg.session <- html_session(rg.url, httr::add_headers(.headers=rg.headers))
rg.session <- rvest:::request_POST(rg.session, url = "https://rotogrinders.com/sign-in",
                                   body = list("username"="*****",
                                                "password"="*****"),
                                   encode = 'json')
```

**My question:** Can someone suggest a way to accomplish in rvest 1.0.0 what I was doing before with rvest 0.3.6? For the time being, I have reverted back 0.3.6 to keep things running smoothly.

Comment: What's going wrong? I get that you are implying it doesn't work, but *implication* is almost always dwarfed by empirical results: warnings, errors, or mis-structured output. And since I don't have an account on rotogrinders, I have nothing at all to go on here. Be warned, though, it's easy to reply to your use of a non-exported function with *"you knew the risks"*.

Comment: The blog with the changes is located here: https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2021/03/rvest-1-0-0/

Comment: @r2evans The following error was in the `rvest:::request_POST` portion of the code: _Error in get(name, envir = asNamespace(pkg), inherits = FALSE) : 
  object 'request_POST' not found_. I was able to resolve this by not using the `request_POST` function at all, suggested in the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can´t comment with my reputation, which is why I will write an answer, even though I am not sure this makes any sense. I dont have a user-account, but with the following I got an "invalid username" result. Which makes sense to me. Maybe with a valid username this works?

```
headers <- c('User-Agent' = 'Mozilla/5.0')
url <- "https://rotogrinders.com/sign-in"
result <-  httr::POST(url = url,
                          httr::add_headers(.headers=headers),
                          body = list("username"="test",
                                      "password"="admin"),
                          encode = 'json')
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you!